# zend htaccess must allow access on /old dir

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I already check all similar titles for this but still havent found one.

I want to use Zend for our new project and what i want to do is to allow access on /old directory which contain our old app.

I try to use this htaccess rules:

```
#old 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

#zend 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

- if visiting root folder, zend handle it properly
- if /old, the error is: the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

What i want is if the user visits the root directory, the zend will handle it.

If they visit the /old, then it will be skipped by zend and will use the index.php of that dir.

thanks in advance

My application structure is

```
/application
/library
.htaccess
index.php - (zend index.php handler)
/old
/old/index.php (old app)
```

my .htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /gabriel/newapp

#old redirect
# if old/ redirect to /old
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

#else zend 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you post you application structure?

Comment: @redmoon7777 - i added the structure. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#old redirect
# if old/ redirect to /old
RewriteRule ^old($|/) - [L]

RewriteBase /gabriel/newapp

#else zend 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: try my new edit. FYI, I'm not an expert, I just know that .htaccess can be a nightmare to figure out.

Comment: hello, sorry but still it didnt work. the error is still **the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.** but thanks for the help.

Comment: yes i just misclick the vote instead of check. thanks again :))